# getting 0xC0000409 when trying to make something with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```java
package me.ricky12awesome.simpleprogram;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("launching....");
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Setting Stage");
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bot manager");

        System.out.println("Setting Burron");
        Button button = new Button("Launch Bot");

        System.out.println("Setting Layout");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        System.out.println("Adding stuff to layout");
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        System.out.println("Adding Scene");
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 480, 360);
        System.out.println("Set Scene");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        System.out.println("Showing..");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I tried many thing to fix this issue but keeps giving me this error
i have a 1080ti with the latest drivers (388.71) so i don't think its a driver issue what else can i do to fix this problem?

EDIT: it gives nothing in console btw also http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/115887/en-us is the oldest driver i can use and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried a different JDK?

Comment: @RonSiven yes i did, also i reset my pc, and it works now, i just have to deal with a bug with cache which should fix itself, i hope

The bug is when i click a link in Discord it freezes, when i did research its a cache issue and should fix it self :/